# Powershell Send Mail Error Messages

Tags: email, powershell

I try to send a email, but i get an error message. I have powershell 4.0, so just for information. I use a GUI, made with PrimalForms. As you can see i try to send from two different mail hosters. Gmail and Hotmail

Error Message:

```
Send-MailMessage : Die E-Mail-Nachricht kann nicht gesendet werden, da kein SMTP-Server angegeben wurde. Sie müssen entweder mit dem 
SmtpServer-Parameter oder der $PSEmailServer-Variablen einen SMTP-Server angeben.
In Zeile:118 Zeichen:9
+         Send-MailMessage -From "$textBox_From.text" -To "$textBox_To. ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

-Body : Die Benennung "-Body" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. 
Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In Zeile:119 Zeichen:9
+         -Body "$textBox_Text.text" -SmtpServer "mail.google.com" -por ...
+         ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Body:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

My Powershell Code:

```
$button_MailSenden_OnClick = {

    if (($textBox_From.TextLength -eq 0) -or
        ($textBox_To.TextLength -eq 0) -or
        ($textBox_Subjekt.TextLength -eq 0) -or
        ($textBox_Text.TextLength -eq 0)) {

        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Bitte füllen Sie alle Kriterien aus." , "Combat 19")

        #Gmail
    } elseif ($radioButton_Gmail.Checked) {

        Send-MailMessage -From "$textBox_From.text" -To "$textBox_To.text" -Subject "$textBox_Subjekt.text"
        -Body "$textBox_Text.text" -SmtpServer "mail.google.com" -port "587"

        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Mail gesendet!" , "Combat 19 - Gmail")

        #Hotmail
        } elseif ($radioButton_Hotmail.Checked) {

        Send-MailMessage -From "$textBox_From.text" -To "$textBox_To.text" -Subject "$textBox_Subjekt.text"
        -Body "$textBox_Text.text" -SmtpServer "smtp.live.com" -port "487"

        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Mail gesendet!" , "Combat 19 - Hotmail")

    }
}
```

Comment: please use english error messages.
Benutz lieber englische Fehlermeldungen, sonst können dir nur weniger Leute helfen.

Comment: Remove the line breaks between `Send-MailMessage` and `-Body ...`

Comment: Okay, it says that -body isnt a cmdlet. I tryed to open it not in PowerGui and it seems to not connect to the smtp server...

Comment: @MarcHofstetter It's because you split it over two lines - it tries to execute `Send-MailMessage` without the `-Body`,`-SmtpServer` and `-Port` parameters, then goes on to the next line and tries to invoke `-Body` as a separate command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Body` is a parameter for `Send-MailMessage` so they both should be on the same line. Maybe you forgot backticks when copying & pasting the code (backticks allow to break long lines). I have put some in my snippet, be careful : ).

Also, you don't need quotes around most of the values you use.

Try this, for example:

```
$button_MailSenden_OnClick = {

    if (($textBox_From.TextLength -eq 0) -or
        ($textBox_To.TextLength -eq 0) -or
        ($textBox_Subjekt.TextLength -eq 0) -or
        ($textBox_Text.TextLength -eq 0)) {

        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Bitte füllen Sie alle Kriterien aus." , "Combat 19")

        #Gmail
    } elseif ($radioButton_Gmail.Checked) {

        Send-MailMessage -From $textBox_From.text `
                         -To $textBox_To.text `
                         -Subject $textBox_Subjekt.text `
                         -Body $textBox_Text.text `
                         -SmtpServer "mail.google.com" `
                         -Port "587"

        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Mail gesendet!" , "Combat 19 - Gmail")

        #Hotmail
        } elseif ($radioButton_Hotmail.Checked) {

        Send-MailMessage -From $textBox_From.text `
                         -To $textBox_To.text `
                         -Subject $textBox_Subjekt.text `
                         -Body $textBox_Text.text `
                         -SmtpServer "smtp.live.com" `
                         -Port "487"

        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Mail gesendet!" , "Combat 19 - Hotmail")

    }
}
```